# Why doesn't ng-class work when simply providing a class name?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jer2/fme6b/1/)

I don't see anything to indicate why this shouldn't work.  The [Angular Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) says "If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names."  What am I doing wrong in this code?

Doesn't work:

```
 <div ng-class="myClass">
    Using ng-class (with no quotes so maybe it doesn't evaluate to a String).
</div>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<div ng-class="'myClass'">
    Using ng-class (with quotes around the class name so it is (?) evaluated to a String).
</div>
```

Works:

```
<div class="myClass">
    Using regular class, no ng-class.
</div>
```

Comment: ng-class wants an expression. If you had $scope.myClass = "some style stuff"; it'd work. ng-class is trying to evaluate `myClass` and it probably does not exist in your controller.

Comment: why are you guys down voting this? It's a perfectly ok question

Comment: `ng-class` is for dynamically adding/removing class(es) based upon conditions. I use class for your case above, but if you wanted to dynamically add a class `foo` use: `ng-class="{'foo': condition}"`

Comment: Your second example should work. Here's a working jsFiddle that is doing something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/MLja9/

Comment: @Rob - you're right, I didn't have the fiddle set up correctly to use Angular.  @R

Comment: +1. I think it's pretty natural at first to think that everything in an angular app needs to be 'ng'-itized, but that's not the case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-class` is for dynamically adding/removing class(es) based upon conditions. I use class for your case above, but if you wanted to dynamically add a class `foo` use: `ng-class="{'foo': condition}"`

The thing to remember is that angular is there to assist you to do dynamic things in-line with standard HTML. So if all you need to do is add a class to an element, just use class.

Answer (score 2):

ng-class will either refer to a scope variable or apply a class dynamically based on an expression output.

Please have a look at this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/BJjB2/4/

For instance:

```
function mainCtl($scope) {
    $scope.myClass = 'myClass';
}
```

Changing $scope.myClass value will update the css class as well.